# VBA Code for Access form Command Control Button for Powerpoint slide output from datafields in form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to push a button in an access form that creates a ppt file with predefined datafields.

I did try this code yet it got stuck at the level of putting a new textbox and data into the slide. All goes well until putting a new slide.

```
Private Sub ExportButton_Click()
On Error Resume Next

' Declare variables
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim strFields As String

' Define list of fields to include in PowerPoint slide
strFields = "ID, Capability, Industrie, Bezeichnungsfeld24"

' Open recordset based on current form's record source
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

' Initialize PowerPoint application and create new presentation
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
pptApp.Visible = True
Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add

' Add new slide to the presentation
Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(pptPresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)

' Loop through the fields and add them as text boxes to the slide
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    If InStr(1, strFields, rs.Fields(i).Name, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Set pptShape = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50, (i + 1) * 50, 300, 50)
        If IsNull(rs.Fields(i).Value) Then
            pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "<null>"
            pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(128, 128, 128) ' Set color of null value to gray
        Else
            pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = rs.Fields(i).Value
        End If
        pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
        pptShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Export complete."
End Sub
```

Comment: And what happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop for fields but no loop for iterating recordset. So only 1 slide is created for one record. If you want a slide for each record, consider:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    ' Add new slide to the presentation

    <continue your code here>

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Export complete."
```